# .NET 6 EF Core - One to Many relationship not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a LINQ expression that is not working correctly, when I see the SQL code generated the LEFT JOIN is not using the right foreign keys.

This is my Entity `InventoryProcessAsset`:

```
public class InventoryProcessAsset
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 InventoryProcessAssetId { get; set; }
        public Int64 InventoryProcessId { get; set; }
        public string AssetId { get; set; }
        public string Epc { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public byte AssetStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AssetIncident> Incidents { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my `AssetIncident` entity:

```
 public class AssetIncident
    {
        [Key]
        public long AssetIncidentId { get; set; }
        public string AssetId { get; set; }
        public DateTime IncidentDate { get; set; }
        public byte IncidentType { get; set; }
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

        public Int64? InventoryProcessId { get; set; }

        public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }

        public virtual InventoryProcessAsset ProcessAsset { get; set; }

    }
```

In my modelBuilder I have the following relation:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryProcessAsset>()
                .HasMany<AssetIncident>(x => x.Incidents)
                .WithOne(g => g.ProcessAsset)
                .HasForeignKey(x=> x.InventoryProcessId);
```

And finally this is my Linq expression:

```
  var dbAssets = await _dbContext.InventoryProcessAssets
                               .Where(i => i.InventoryProcessId == processId)
                               .Include(a=> a.Incidents)
                               .ToListAsync();
```

When I see the SQL generated this is what I get:

[image]

So `[t].[InventoryProcessAssetId]` should be `[t].[InventoryProcessId]`

That's why is not bringing any data.

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: I am not able to understand what kind of relationship you want to build across these entities using fluent API, ex *one-to-one, one  to many or many to many* if it is one to many this link might help https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: You defined `AssetIncident.InventoryProcessId` as FK to `InventoryProcessAsset`. You probably confused yourself. At any rate, the code obeys the configuration.

Comment: I wanted to join using a different key that is not the primary key. So maybe that wrong. Or maybe I can use just linq

Comment: No, FK's always point to the PK. Your entities are breaking relational DB rules.

Comment: That's makes a lot of sense. You are 100% right. Thanks